# Quotations within apostrophes. How?

Tags: php, html, mysql, dreamweaver, quote

```
 <?php $r = mysql_query("select * from tbl_student_master where email='@$_SESSION[email]'") or die(mysql_error());
```

There seems to be a problem with that. How do I properly enter the session variable within apostrophes?

Comment: Do you really want that `@`?  That's doing error suppression, and if you're querying against your table using potentially missing session vars, you've got bigger fish to fry.

Comment: Adn *what specifically* seems to be the problem with your code? What does mysql_error say? Or did you wonder why the stray @ does not lead to matches?

Answer (score 2):

First off, make sure that your $_SESSION variable is safe - I have no reason to assume that it isn't, but if you are initially getting it from $_GET or $_POST or $_REQUEST, you need to do this differently.

```
<?php $r = mysql_query("select * from tbl_student_master where email='" . $_SESSION["email"] . "'") or die(mysql_error());
```

That being said, mysql_query is deprecated, you should really look into either mysqli or PDO.  I strongly recommend PDO.

If you are using the @ because it is sometimes not set, you should wrap it in

```
if (isset($_SESSION["email"])) {
 $r = mysql_query("select * from tbl_student_master where email='" . $_SESSION["email"] . "'") or die(mysql_error());
}
else {
  //what to do if there is no session email
}
```